# Pan-frying fish filets with skin on

Tags: frying, fish

When frying filets with skin on, the piece of fish curls and doesn't cook evenly.

I've been told to score the skin with a paring knife. Will this work to stop the curling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tried and tested method for solving this is simple. As you add each fillet to a hot pan press down for 60 seconds then repeat as you add more fillets. If you are good you could do a fillet with each hand so as to make the process quicker.

Another really good method, and my favourite. Use a cold pan. Simply oil a decent non stick pan, put your fish in then put the pan on the heat as high as it'll go. You still get nice crisp skin but no curling.